# SQL Server: How to convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have a table where I store column name and its value ticker & client wise.

This is my table with data. screen shot attached.
[image]

Here i tried this sql which is throwing error for duplicate values in field name. i got this code from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745076/9359783

But their code is not working for my scenario. please guide me what i need to alter in code.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
                    from DynamicForm WHERE Ticker='X' AND ClientCode='Z'
                    group by FieldName, id,Ticker,ClientCode
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select value, FieldName
                from DynamicForm WHERE Ticker=''X'' AND ClientCode=''Z''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for FieldName in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

### OUTPUT would be look like

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| Last Update |        Broker        |     Analyst     |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 7/6/2021    |    JMP Securities    | David M Scharf  |
| 4/28/2021   |  Argus Research Corp | David E Coleman |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

See here two records is coming and JMP Securities  is getting first records because its orderid is **1. so data should be displayed as per Ticker & client code wise and orderId wise data should be order.**

Here is script which help you to get data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DynamicForm](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Order] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (1, N'Last Update
', N'4/28/2021
', N'X', N'Z', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (2, N'Broker
', N'Argus Research Corp
', N'X', N'Z', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (3, N'Analyst 
', N'David E Coleman
', N'X', N'Z', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (4, N'Last Update
', N'7/6/2021
', N'X', N'Z', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (5, N'Broker
', N'JMP Securities
', N'X', N'Z', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] ([ID], [FieldName], [Value], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [Order]) VALUES (6, N'Analyst 
', N'David M Scharf
', N'X', N'Z', 2)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DynamicForm] OFF
GO
```

Comment: if i do as you said then multiple value is not coming. my requirement is to show all values for specific ticker & client code. how to achieve it

Comment: it is unfair to underrate answers. My answer was based on your previous question. later you edit the question when I asked and showed you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here i tried this sql which is throwing error for duplicate values in field name.

This is because your `GROUP BY` is on `FieldName, id,Ticker,ClientCode`. You are therefore telling the RDBMS you want a row for *every* **distinct** group of those columns, and very clearly that would result in multiple rows for the same value of `FieldName`.

Very likely the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` shouldn't be there at all:

```sql
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
                      FROM dbo.DynamicForm
                      WHERE Ticker='X'
                        AND ClientCode='Z'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') ,1,1,'');
```

---

Now we have sample data, I can provide a full solution. Personally, as well, I would use a conditional aggregate, rather than the restrictive `PIVOT` operator, and build my entire statement in one go. I continue to use `FOR XML PATH` as I *assume* you used it (rather than `STRING_AGG`) due to being on SQL Server 2016 or prior.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF + N'       ' +
                                      N'MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName,'''') + N' THEN Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
                               FROM dbo.DynamicForm
                               GROUP BY FieldName
                               ORDER BY MIN(ID)
                               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.DynamicForm' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE Ticker = @Ticker' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND ClientCode = @ClientCode' + @CRLF + 
           N'GROUP BY [Order]' + @CRLF + --ORDER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
           N'ORDER BY [Order];'; --ORDER is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names

DECLARE @Ticker varchar(10) = 'X',
        @ClientCode varchar(10) = 'Z';

--Print @SQL; -- Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Ticker varchar(10), @ClientCode varchar(10)', @Ticker, @ClientCode;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c27331f81bb205a10e6414dafa2aeb6c)

Comment: Sir now script is working but it is showing single data but i have to show multiple data for that ticker & client code wise.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run the above SQL, as I don't have access to your instance, and we don't have your expected results. If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68726792/edit) your question to include **consumable** sample data and expected results, @BabuBhatt , that'll greatly help. This, at present answers why you were getting an error, which is what you were asking about.

Comment: Also, please don't assume the genders of the users here; I don't state anywhere what my gender is and you could very easily offend a user here by assuming they are male, @BabuBhatt .

Comment: Sorry Sir/Madam.

Comment: You're better off with gender neutral language, @BabuBhatt . It is what you agreed to use in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: sure i will do it from next time

Comment: I did this changes but still no luck. `set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N',ticker, clientcode from 
             (
                select value, fieldname, ticker, clientcode
                from DynamicForm WHERE Ticker=''X'' AND ClientCode=''Z''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for FieldName in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '`

Comment: ... Edit your question as I asked in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726792/sql-server-how-to-convert-rows-to-columns/68726899?noredirect=1#comment121459300_68726899), @BabuBhatt .

Comment: @Larnu Since you are using Distinct (By looking at the provided data) you dont need a where clause here.

Comment: @BabuBhatt Your where clause inside dynamic PIVOT which filters records gives you single row as a result. Check  my answer. I mentioned it there.

Comment: i have edited my questions and there i mention what output should be. please have a look. thanks

Comment: i have seen if i remove where clause then still getting same output....no luck.

Comment: Without consumable sample data, I can't help you, @BabuBhatt . I can't copy text out of an image.

Comment: @Larnu please check my post. now i shared script which you can copy and get data. thanks

Comment: @Larnu this line is not clear. how does it create field by field `N'MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName,'''') + N' THEN Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)` in select ?

Comment: @Larnu can i filter data by ticker & client code where using Stuff() function like `                                      N'MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName,'''') + N' THEN Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
                               FROM dbo.DynamicForm
          WHERE Ticker=''X'' AND ClientCode = ''Z''` if i do not filter here then stuff will load all data irrespective of ticker & client code. so i like to use filter here too and as well as filter will be there in outer query too which is present now. thanks

Comment: It's called conditional aggregation, @BabuBhatt . As I said, I used this instead of the more restrictive `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: *"an i filter data by ticker & client code"* yes, you can parametrise the `FOR XML PATH` query too.

Comment: i am not good in sql. please add one more ticker & client code filter in the select where Stuff() has been used.

Comment: @BabuBhatt with the greatest respect, it's you who needs to understand the query. Parametrising a query isn't particularly difficult. If you uncomment the `PRINT` statement you can see an example of it in the dynamic statement... You just need to add the same clauses in `WHERE` that are in the dynamic statement (look at lines 10 and 11).

Comment: sure i will try & let you know face any difficulties. thank you so much

Comment: @Larnu what is the reason for using XML as the expectation is in PIVOT in the question ?

Comment: @Gudwlk that is for the String Aggregation, not the pivoting.

Comment: But same thing you can try with PIVOT as well. it might be a less complicated solution as well.  @Larnu

Comment: From the answe @Gudwlk ... *"Personally, as well, I would use a conditional aggregate, rather than the restrictive `PIVOT` operator"*, that is why I don't use `PIVOT`.

Answer (score -2):

If you change the query which assigns values to @Col variable as below added your query will work. To define a table columns they should be identical. No table can have two columns with same name. That was your error given by the code. But I am not sure about your expected output. As I see a where clause which filters data I hope your answer will have only one row.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
                from DynamicForm                    -              
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


  set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select  value, FieldName
            from DynamicForm WHERE Ticker=''X'' AND ClientCode=''Z''
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(value)
            for FieldName in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

   exec sp_executesql @query;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: How does this differ from my answer (which was posted 50~ minutes prior to yours)?

Comment: @Larnu once after posted I saw your answer :( Sorry about that. if you are to keep the answer I will remove mine.

Comment: i have edited my questions and there i mention what output should be. please have a look. thanks